# Copy data from one row to another SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 rows.

First row has figure in value1 and value2 columns.

Second row has figure in value1 but nothing in value2 Column.

How can I get the figure in value1 from first row into column2 on second row

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *figure* ? Data ?

Comment: can you show example data?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: There is no "first" or "second" row unless you determine an order from a column or set of columns. You can use LAG function to retrieve the previous row's values, given a specific ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can query like this:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `value2` = 
      (SELECT `value1` FROM `table_name` LIMIT 1) 
WHERE `value1` = 
      (SELECT ``value1` FROM `table_name` LIMIT 1,1)
```